# passing control+C in linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

in a shell script i have a command like, pid -p PID, after that i have some more commands. but as soon as the pid -p PID command runs we should supply a control+C to exit from it and then only the further commands executes. so i wanna do this periodically, i have all the things i want in a shell script and i wanna put this into crontab. the only thing that bothers is, if i schedule this script in the crontab, afetr its first execution, the command pid -p PID, how will i supply the CONTRO+C command for allowing further commands to execute???? please help
my script is like this.. very simple one

```
top -p $1
free -m
netstat -antp|grep 3306|grep $1
jmap -dump:file=my_stack$RANDOM.bin $1
```

Comment: `kill -INT $pid` doesn't work for you?

Comment: BTW, what does the `pid` command do? `man pid` on my system did not find any manual entry.

Comment: PID is not the command, its a variale, top -p is the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send signals with [`kill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill). In your case however, you can just restrict [`top`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) to one or a few iterations

```
top -p $1 -n 1
```

*Update:*

You can redirect the output of a command to a file. Either overwrite the file each time

```
command.sh >file.txt 2>&1
```

or append to a file

```
command.sh >>file.txt 2>&1
```

If you don't want the error output, leave out the `2>&1` part.

Answer (score 0):

```
pid -p PID &
some_pid=$!
kill -s INT $some_pid
```

Comment: i used it like this

top -p $1
#some_pid=$!
#kill -INT $some_pid
free -m
netstat -antp|grep 3306|grep $1

jmap -dump:file=my_stack$RANDOM.bin $1


i got this error it says kill command usage not proper - "kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]"

Comment: You and I are using different versions of kill. `man kill` tells me the syntax to be `kill [ -signal | -s signal ] pid ...` which is what I have always used. You should try this with the -s option.